# Issues saving session objects using simple-injector

Tags: asp.net-mvc, simple-injector

I have MVC application where I am trying to save some objects in session using DI framework of simple injector.
I register the objects as below

```
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<Func<HttpSessionState>>(() => 
    () => HttpContext.Current.Session);
container.RegisterSingle<MemoryCache>(() => MemoryCache.Default);
container.RegisterPerWebRequest<ISessionCacheService, SessionCacheService>();
```

Now in the session service constructor I am able to see the multi-cast delegate for sessionstate object but when I try to add other objects I get the Object reference error. The constructor is listed below

```
protected internal Func<HttpSessionState> _HttpSessionState;
public SessionCacheService(Func<HttpSessionState> httpSessionState)
{
    _HttpSessionState = httpSessionState;
}
```

I get the error in the following line of code inside a method of this service

```
public void Set<T>(string key, T data)
{
    _HttpSessionState()[key] = data;
}
```

Here I can see that the following variable is null

```
this._HttpSessionState()
```

The main reason why we need to use this construct is that we need to store multicast delegate to session as shown in the example below

```
public RuntimeContext Current
{
    get
    {
        Func<RuntimeContext> getRuntimeContextFunc = () =>
        {
            return new RuntimeContext() 
            { 
                ImpersonatingAgentId = Guid.Empty 
            };
        };
        return this._SessionCacheService.Get<RuntimeContext>(
            typeof(RuntimeContext).ToString(), 
            getRuntimeContextFunc);
    }
}
```

Later on we can retrieve these items from session using the get method

```
public T Get<T>(string key, Func<T> acquire)
{
    if (this.IsSet(key))
    {
        return this.Get<T>(key);
    }
    else
    {
        var result = acquire();
        this.Set<T>(key, result);
        return result;
    }
}
```

Comment: My web.config looks like this   <sessionState mode="SQLServer" cookieless="false" timeout="100" allowCustomSqlDatabase="true" sqlConnectionString="Persist Security Info=False;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=MySessionDB;server=.;Current Language=English;Connection Timeout=240;" />

Comment: Why do you use a `Func`? Why not use `container.Register<HttpSessionState>(() => HttpContext.Current.Session);`

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have provided supporting code in the original question to explain why we need to store a set of delegates in the session.

Comment: It's really hard to figure out what you are trying to do from the code snippets provided. I can't guess what code I need to add to join it all together. http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve